# Jenkins pipeline: parallel steps inside a for

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a pipeline process with a dynamic number of steps. Thoses steps could run in parallel, but I ~think~ the language won't suport this case. Am I wrong?

The folowing example shows the situation:

```
def parallelFor() {
  variables = ['alfa', 'beta', 'gama', 'delta', 'eta', 'lambda']

  for ( variable in variables ) {
    stage("Stage ${variable}") {
      // bogus code
      println "Building stage: " + variable
      sleep 1
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make each stage in this for run in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have parallel stages. You can only execute steps in parallel within a single stage.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for dynamic set of stages:

```
def parallelFor() {
  variables = ['alfa', 'beta', 'gama', 'delta', 'eta', 'lambda']

  for ( variable in variables ) {
    parallelStage(variable)
  }
}

def parallelStage (variable) {
  stage name: "Stage of ${variable}"
  println "Building stage: " + variable
  sleep 1

}
```

Still, it cannot be run in parallel since **parallel steps** can only run within a stage.